# Dereferencing pointer to incomplete type ‘struct'

Tags: c, struct, typedef

In "esame.h" I have declared `typedef struct esame *esame;` and in "esame.c" I have declared:

```
struct esame{
    char corso[20];
    int voto;
    char data[11];
};
```

In "libretto.h" I have declared `typedef struct libretto *libretto;` and in "libretto.c" I have declared:

```
struct libretto{
    esame esami[MAXESAMI];
};
```

But if for example I try to `printf` this

```
printf("Corso: %s\nVoto: %d\nData: %s\n", l->esami[i]->corso, l->esami[i]->voto, l->esami[i]->data);
```

it gives me this error, why?

```
error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type ‘struct esame’
    printf("Corso: %s\nVoto: %d\nData: %s\n", l->esami[i]->corso, l->esami[i]->voto, l->esami[i]->data);
```

Comment: `esame esami[MAXESAMI];` -> `struct esame esami[MAXESAMI];`

Comment: @EugeneSh. array type has incomplete element type ‘struct esame’
  struct esame esami[MAXESAMI];

Comment: The `struct` declarations should be in header files too, and, it's better to avoid the `typedef` of pointers.

Comment: @WeatherVane I added the two structs in header files too and it gives me more errors

Comment: Please make a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use to declare types in the header file and then define them in the implementation one as you did, but in a sligtly different manner. This how I do:

- In the header file

```
typedef struct{
    char corso[20];
    int voto;
    char data[11];
}esame, *ptr_esame;
```

- In the implementation file you can then use the types as follows:

```
esame esami[MAXESAMI];
ptr_esame testa = esami;
```

I do not really know why this `typedef struct esame *esame;` is sintactically correct, cause even by reading it doesn't make sense. Anyway, none of my business.

Keep in mind that when header files are included by multiple sources, redefinition may happen very easily, so use precompiler guards to avoid those issues.

```
#ifndef __ESAME_H__
#define __ESAME_H__

typedef struct{
    char corso[20];
    int voto;
    char data[11];
}esame, *ptr_esame;

...

#endif
```